# Some parts are configured in Spanish in spite of me selecting English during installer

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, language-support

During the Kubuntu 21.xx installation process I selected only English. I set my location to Madrid.

I'm seeing several apps which have parts of the UI in Spanish. This bothers me but I can live with it. The `mainline` app (which fetches kernel updates) is one that shows the UI in Spanish, and I noticed that now after upgrading the kernel my console shows messages in Spanish, which I definitely don't want.

How can I use my system only in English?

Thank you!

Comment: Please be specific with release details; there is no 21.xx.   Was in the 2021 April (21.04) or 2021 October (21.10) release of Kubuntu; as they are different products.

Comment: go to language and region, select the language you want and click on use systemwide,you might have to remove spanish language but i do not think so.